# How do I access Microsoft Graph API with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, microsoft-graph-api

I've found a lot of tutorials that have gotten me as far as logging in with OAuth in Meteor / MeteorAngular.  Unfortunately, they've never gotten me as far as successfully accessing the Microsoft graph API.  I know I need to (somehow) transform my user access token into a bearer token, but I haven't found any guides on how to do that in Meteor -- and the sample Node apps I've found to do similar things don't run out of the box, either.  I have some routes that should return the data I need, I just can't quite seem to hit them.

Comment: at a guess, I think you might be in a very lonely place :)  you may have to build your own bridges, or your own authentication provider based on MS Graph

Comment: @KeithNicholas yeah, I have a strong suspicion that's the case -- and alas, I can't make heads or tales of Microsoft's documentation on the subject.  As I've been telling my boss, every time you pick a new stack, you cut your slice of the 'internet pie' even smaller.  Javascript is big, Node is small.  Meteor is smaller still.  Meteor + Microsoft... is darned near nonexistent, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Microsoft is pretty committed to Node, so I'd expect first class support for it to come,  marrying it to meteor will be a bit of manual work

Comment: @KeithNicholas they 'have' a node example out.  Too bad the sample app doesn't actually work.

Comment: @RonLugge any luck with this?

Comment: @AlfredYoung I'm sorry to say that it's been long enough that not only is my memory too vague to be significantly helpful, I no longer have access to the code base in question.  That said, as I recall I found a package that helped with some of the issues (logging in and requesting data) and had to hack the package's code.  The big issue that stumped me for weeks was that I had to change the login url -- the difference between the packaging using signin.microsoft.com when I needed login.windows.com; something small, subtle, and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

> Meteor + Microsoft... is darned near nonexistent, as far as I can tell

lol you aren't wrong. However as one of the primary engineers behind [Sidekick AI](https://sidekickai.com/) (a scheduling app integrating with Microsoft+Google calendar built with Meteor) I have some very practical examples of using said `access_token` to work with the Microsoft Graph API with Meteor.

Here's some examples of functions I've written which use the `access_token` to communicate with the Graph API to work with calendars. Notably the line that matters is where I'm setting

```js
Authorization: `Bearer ${sources.accessToken} // Sources just being the MongoDB collection we store that info in
```

**NOTE:** if you need more I'd be happy to provide but didn't want to clutter this initially

**NOTE:** wherever you see "Outlook" it really should say "Microsoft"; that's just a symptom of uninformed early development.

```js
/**
 * This function will use the Meteor HTTP package to make a POST request
 * to the Microsoft Graph Calendar events endpoint using an access_token to create a new
 * Event for the connected Outlook account
 * 
 * @param { String } sourceId The Sources._id we are using tokens from for the API request
 * 
 * @param { Object } queryData Contains key value pairs which will describe the new Calendar
 * Event
 * 
 * @returns { Object } The newly created Event Object
 */
export const createOutlookCalendarEvent = async (
    sourceId: string,
    queryData: {
        subject: any
        start: {
            dateTime: any
            timeZone: string
        }
        end: {
            dateTime: any
            timeZone: string
        }
        isOnlineMeeting: any
        body: {
            content: string
            contentType: string
        },
        attendees: {
            emailAddress: {
                address: string
                name: string
            }
        }[]
    }
): Promise<object> => {
    await attemptTokenRefresh(sourceId)
    const sources = Sources.findOne({ _id: sourceId })

    const options = {
        headers: {
            Accept: `application/json`,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sources.accessToken}`,
        },

        data: queryData,
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        HTTP.post(`${OauthEndpoints.Outlook.events}`, options, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(handleError(`Failed to create a new Outlook Calendar event`, error, { options, sourceId, queryData, sources }))
            } else {
                resolve(response.data)
            }
        })
    })
}

/**
 * This function will use the Meteor HTTP package to make a GET request
 * to the Microsoft Graph Calendars endpoint using an access_token obtained from the
 * Microsoft common oauth2 v2.0 token endpoint. It retrieves Objects describing the calendars
 * under the connected account
 * 
 * @param sourceId The Sources._id we are using tokens from for the API request
 * 
 * @returns Contains Objects describing the user's connected account's calendars
 */
export const getCalendars = async (sourceId: string): Promise<Array<any>> => {
    await attemptTokenRefresh(sourceId)
    const sources = Sources.findOne({ _id: sourceId })

    const options = {
        headers: {
            Accept: `application/json`,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sources.accessToken}`,
        },
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        HTTP.get(OauthEndpoints.Outlook.calendars, options, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(handleError(`Failed to retrieve the calendars for a user's connected Outlook account`, error, { options, sources, sourceId }))
            } else {
                resolve(response.data.value)
            }
        })
    })
}



// reference for the afore-mentioned `OauthEndpoints`
/**
 * Object holding endpoints for our Oauth integrations with Google,
 * Microsoft, and Zoom
 */
export const OauthEndpoints = {
    ...

    Outlook: {
        auth: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?',
        token: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        calendars: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars',
        calendarView: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView',
        events: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events',
        messages: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages',
        sendMail: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail',
    },

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd love to accept this comment as an answer -- it looks like it might be.  Unfortunately, I no longer work in Meteor JS (or even JS in general -- pure Ruby / SQL), I no longer have access to the project in question, I no longer even work at the same place.  I can't validate the accuracy of your response past 'this looks cool'.

Comment: @RonLugge no worries . life moves on. hopefully this helps someone else someday.